# running C++ exe from servlet

Tags: java, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, servlets

I am running a server on my machine. When Servlet receives a message, the corresponding Visual C++ ".exe" need to start running.

I am using following code to start the exe. But I am getting "Microsoft Visual C++ Debug Error". The code is as follows:-

```
if(strLine.equals(location))//same place do not do anything             
{                   
Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();  
String cmd[]={"cmd.exe", "/c", "C:\\Users\\nabeel.OUCS1289\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Scene Localization - (FM)\\Debug\\Scene Localization.exe"};                    
rt.exec(cmd);
System.out.println("Same place so dont do anyuthing");          
}
```

Please help me out in this regard.

Comment: You could post the exact error and/or try the Release version of your exe rather than the debug version

Answer (score 0):

The EXE file to be executed is located in a user profile directory. Does the account running the JRE/Webserver does have read & execute permissions on that particular directory?

Furthermore remove the indirect execution via `cmd.exe /c ...`. This is total unnecessary for regular executables. It is only required in case you are executing a command that is provided by cmd.exe itself and therefore can not be executed via an exe file.

Comment: hi i tried to put exe in folder in some other drive but some issue. . . i will post the exact error soon ! ! One more thing is servelet capable of running the external exe ?